# MySQL syntax to combine row count in one table with select results from another table

Tags: mysql, syntax, subquery

In my MySQL database I have two tables.

```
Table contact_groups:
+-------------+-----------+
| groupname   | fieldname |
+-------------+-----------+
| Wholesalers | grp_whs   |
| Retailers   | grp_rtl   |
| Consumers   | grp_cns   |
+-------------+-----------+

Table contacts:
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| name    | grp_whs | grp_rtl | grp_cns |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| Tom     |       0 |       1 |       1 |
| Dick    |       1 |       0 |       0 |
| Harry   |       0 |       1 |       0 |
| John    |       0 |       1 |       1 |
| Jane    |       1 |       1 |       0 |
| Anna    |       1 |       0 |       0 |
| Bob     |       0 |       0 |       1 |
| Charlie |       0 |       1 |       1 |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

I need to write a single qyery that returns a list of field names and group names from the **contact_groups** table, with the number of names from the **contacts** table associated with that group concatenated to the group name. In case of the above data, that would return the following:

```
+-----------+-----------------+
| fieldname | groupname       |
+-----------+-----------------+
| grp_whs   | Wholesalers (3) |
| grp_rtl   | Retailers (5)   |
| grp_cns   |  Consumers (4)  |
+-----------+-----------------+
```

(The reason why I need a single query producing the above output in this format is that this statement will be executed by a form generator that lack flexibility and can only execute one single query that must return fieldname and group names in this manner.)

How do I do this?

Comment: use the `pivot` table method.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the ans to be in this specific format use CONCAT(groupname, '(', value,')' )
you will get some thing like this Wholesalers (3).

Answer (score 1):

This is what I could think off

```
select fieldname, concat(groupname,' (',
case
  when fieldname = 'grp_whs' then 
  (
     select sum(grp_whs) from contacts
  )  
  when fieldname = 'grp_rtl' then 
  (
     select sum(grp_rtl) from contacts
  ) 
  when fieldname = 'grp_cns' then 
  (
     select sum(grp_cns) from contacts
  ) 
END
,' )') as groupname
from contact_groups
```

Check here

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a235f/4

I am assuming you have only 3 fieldname . If there are more than that then I do not think its the best solution , someone may have a better idea on this.

But for your case this should work.

Answer (score 0):

try...

```
  select fieldname ,

    case  fieldname 
       when 'grp_whs'
       then groupname  + '(' + convert(varchar(50),(select count(name) from contacts where grp_whs=1)) + ')'
       when 'grp_rtl'
       then groupname  + '(' + convert(varchar(50),(select count(name) from contacts where grp_rtl=1)) + ')'
       when 'grp_cns'
       then groupname  + '(' + convert(varchar(50),(select count(name) from contacts where grp_cns=1)) + ')'

    END as groupname

    FROM contact_groups
```

Comment: Not sure that's how you use convert... :-) Also, the fieldnames are variable (may be changed, added or removed) so hardcoding them into the statement is not an option; I need to do the above on the basis of whatever happens to be in the contact_groups table.